# C++ error (assigning to TreeNode* from incompatible type'void')

Tags: c++, c++11

I am implementing a tree node function. But I am stuck at delete node. 
It keeps giving this error. I have tried this with TreeNode* function and it totally works but this one keeps giving an error when I tried to change it to a void function.

I am trying to change this into a void function.

```
void Tree::deleteFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int value)



 //from example in class, deleting a node


if (startintPoint == nullptr)
{
    return;
}
else if (startintPoint->left != nullptr && value < startintPoint->value)
{
    startintPoint->left = deleteFrom(startintPoint->left, value);
}
else if (startintPoint->right != nullptr && value > startintPoint->value)
{
    startintPoint->right = deleteFrom(startintPoint->right, value);
}
else
{
    if (startintPoint->left == nullptr && startintPoint->right == nullptr)
    {
        delete startintPoint;
        startintPoint = nullptr;
    }
    else if (startintPoint->left == nullptr)
    {
        TreeNode* temp = startintPoint;
        startintPoint = startintPoint->right;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if (startintPoint->right == nullptr)
    {
        TreeNode* temp = startintPoint;
        startintPoint = startintPoint->left;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
    {
        TreeNode* temp = findMinValue(startintPoint->right);
        startintPoint->value = temp->value;
        startintPoint->right = deleteFrom(startintPoint->right, temp->value);
    }


   }

    return startintPoint;
}
```

Comment: You assign like `startintPoint->left = deleteFrom(...)`, but `deleteFrom`'s return value is of type `void`, i.e. `void deleteFrom(...)`. So it won't return any value that could be assigned.

Comment: `return startintPoint` at the bottom of this function should draw a direct concusion that `void` is the wrong return type for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the return type of the function is `void`, the compiler does not like the lines

```
startintPoint->left = deleteFrom(startintPoint->left, value);
```

and

```
startintPoint->right = deleteFrom(startintPoint->right, value);
```

The RHS of those statements is of type `void` while the LHS is of type `TreeNode*`.

You need to change the return type of the function to `TreeNode*`. That will allow you to use lines.

And then make sure to return the right pointer from the function, which you seem to be already doing.

Answer (score 0):

You assign like `startintPoint->left = deleteFrom(...)`, but `deleteFrom`'s return value is of type `void`, i.e. `void deleteFrom(...)`. So it won't return any value that could be assigned.

You could change `void Tree::deleteFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int value)` into `TreeNode* Tree::deleteFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int value)`.

If you want to leave `deleteFrom` as it is, you could introduce an additional (probably protected or private function) like `TreeNode* Tree::deleteFromRecursive(TreeNode* startintPoint, int value)` which call itself recursively and which is called once by `deleteFrom`.